# Assembla Wiki making random words links

Tags: wiki, assembla

We're using Assembla for some wiki functionality. It's mostly fine, although it's turning random words in links as can be seen in HashCode below. There is nothing visible through either the visual editor or in the HTML source, so we have no idea why it's underlining them. The link goes to assembla.com/

[image: Random underlined words]

Any ideas why this could be happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evan, sounds like you need to go to the wiki settings in your Assembla project and uncheck "Use CamelCase links" for wiki page. When this is enabled, words like CamelCase or HashCode will be automatically linked to wiki pages with the same name.